# Front USB 2.0 Type C not working

Tags: usb, motherboard, android, usb-c

I have this PC case:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Chieftec-HC-10B-OP-Computer-Case-Black/dp/B07JKKLLHS

And this Motherboard:
[https://www.amazon.com/ASUS-P8Z77-V-PRO-Intel-Motherboard/dp/B007G51UV0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007G51UV0)

I've connected all of the cables to my MOBO, the connector for the USB Type C is 2.0.
But when I plug in my Galaxy A13 cable to transfer data, nothing happens, it doesn't charge, nothing pops up on the screen, like I haven't plugged it into anything.

I've then purchased USB C to A cable and connected the phone to the PC (in USB A port), but I only get a notification that my phone is in slow charging mode, no option to switch to data/file transfer, just charging.

I have no idea what's going on here, I've ordered USB C to A adapter, it has yet to arrive.
Does anybody know what the problem here is?

To summarize:

- Front USB 2.0 C type isn't working.
- New C to A cable is only charging phone in slow mode, without any option to transfer files.

I've tried with USB debugging enabled but nothing works, even switching to MTP using keypad codes, nothing.

I've tried switching places for USB C and two USB 2.0 ports on my motherboard. Front USB 2.0 A type ports work, and Type C still doesn't work. I'm out of options, I hate when I have a port but it's not functional.

Comment: It seems your phone doesn't like USB2.0. Your USB-C to USB-A cable is likely USB2.0 only so it changes, slowly, but nothing else.

Comment: I have thought of that, but I didn't think it would refuse the data transfer. Well, I guess I'll just have to wait for the adapter to arrive and see if I can transfer then. Thanks.I don't think I can accept a comment as a solution on stackexchange.

Comment: Converting USB 2.0 to Type-C could very well cause it to lose the ability to transfer data.

Comment: @ChanganAuto My Baseus USB C to A converter has just arrived. You were right. I'm not sure if it supports 3.0 or what but with it fast charging works as well as data transfer to the PC without any issues at all, on Linux.

Not sure if there's an option to accept a comment as a solution or set it as a helpful answer, can't find that button anywhere.

As far as Ramhound's comment, I wasn't converting USB  2.0 to Type C. My front panel was Type C which has USB 2.0 connector to the motherboard, and NOT your typical new Type C connector. Anyways, it's solved with this new adapter.